# Quartz.net scheduler isn't staying alive

Tags: c#, unit-testing, quartz.net

After reading through some SO Q&A, I'm taking the recommended approach of NOT writing my own scheduler. I've opted to use Quartz.net, as it looks to do exactly what I need. According to their quick start guide, the application should not shut down once a scheduler is instantiated until I call the shutdown method on the scheduler:
http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/quick-start.html

I am testing this out in a unit test, and I'm finding that my nUnit test is closing without me calling shutdown on the scheduler! I made my scheduler a singleton, assuming that would fix it, but no such luck. Is this behavior specific to unit testing? I'm assuming that since it happens in my tests, it will happen when I use it in my console app later on.

Here is how I put together my scheduler:

```
public static class Scheduler
{
    public static IScheduler LocalScheduler { get; private set; }

    static Scheduler()
    {
        // get a scheduler
        ISchedulerFactory schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        LocalScheduler = schedFact.GetScheduler();
    }

    public static void ScheduleJob(IJobDetail job, ITrigger trigger)
    {
        LocalScheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
    }

    public static void Start()
    {
        if (!LocalScheduler.IsStarted) LocalScheduler.Start();
    }

    public static void Stop()
    {
        LocalScheduler.Shutdown();
    }

}
```

The unit test in particular that is failing is:

```
    [Test, Explicit]
    public void JobExecutionTest()
    {
        var start = new DateTime(2014,06,01);
        var stop = new DateTime(2014,06,10);

        // I made my own factories for the JobDataMap, IJobDetail, and ITrigger. 
        var jobMap = JobDataFactory.CreateConnectwiseMap(start, stop);
        var job = JobFactory.CreateParameterJob<ConnectwiseJob>("testjob", "testgroup", jobMap);
        // fire in 5 seconds for testing
        var trigger = TriggerFactory.CreateRecurring("testtrigger", "testgroup", DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(5));
        Scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
        Scheduler.Start();
        // it shuts down almost immediately!
    }
```

I put a breakpoint in the job that is supposed to execute to see if it ever gets hit, and it never does because the unit test thinks its all done and closes everything. I don't want to use Thread.Sleep() if I can avoid it, as when I use this scheduler elsewhere I don't want it to sit there in that state. Would wiring up a listener prevent it from dying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your scheduler is shutting down because the test is finishing and garbage collecting everything. If you really wanted to give the scheduler time to finish its thing you would have to find a way of keeping the test running by adding a Thread.Sleep statement just after the Scheduler.Start(); method.

However, you really don't want to test your jobs this way though. You should mock out the IJobExecutionContext and pass it to your job to execute.

Comment: That is what I thought. I've been using Thread.Sleep after I posted the question, and its working as I'm doing a while jobcount > 0 spin kind of thing. I agree with the mock, I will do that for unit testing. In regards to the scheduler dying during the way I have it now, I tried to model it like it would be in actual use. Does this mean I still need to deal with it using Thread.Sleep or something similar?

Comment: "in the real world" you would either run the scheduler as a stand alone windows service, in which case the scheduler will stay alive. OR you would embedded in your application, in which case if you create it as a singleton you'll be ok as long as your application doesn't shut down.

Comment: Yep, I plan on putting it in a windows service. If placed in the service startup is good enough and there is no need for a while(true) loop, I'll be very happy!

Comment: To OP.  A quartz-service has already be done....I would get it instead of rolling your own, or at least use it as a starting point.   https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/tree/master/server/Quartz.Server

Comment: Or do a google search for this file name : "QuartzServerFactory.cs".

Answer (score 0):

Having worked with earlier version of quartz, I remember that the scheduler fires the job in a thread (or more). Thats maybe what you then experience. So maybe you should test using another approach.

Regards Frank

Comment: The docs say it goes on the regular ThreadPool, but doesn't state if its a foreground/background thread. I'm guessing background thread because the app doesn't stay alive?

Comment: One way or the other, I would do the Integration Test by running the job using the scheduler, but check for output/result from the expected job run, meaning you would have to do a Thread.Sleep